# Passing associated array from PHP to AS3 issue

Tags: php, arrays, actionscript-3, flash

I'm having a problem with passing my JSON (Converted to Array) data from PHP to ActionScript 3.0 .

Here is my php code:

```
class myTwitterOAuth {

    public function get_user($username) {

        $oauth = new TwitterOAuth($consumer_key, $consumer_secret, $access_token, $access_token_secret);
        $param = array('screen_name'=>'twitter');
        $data = $oauth->get('users/show', $param);
        $json = json_encode($data);
        $JSONarray=json_decode($json, true);
        return $JSONarray; //To pass the whole Array not working
    }
}
```

Now for my Action Script Method:

```
function whenSuccess(res:Object):void{  
    trace(res['name']); //Not working at all Neither name nor screen_name or any
}
```

Error I'm getting from Adobe Flash:

```
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
    at AS3PHPTesting01_fla::MainTimeline/whenSuccess()
```

**UPDATE**

I'm using Amfphp library to communicate between PHP and Action Script. Here is how I'm doing it:

```
var gateway:String = "http://website/here/Amfphp/index.php";
var connection:NetConnection = new NetConnection();
connection.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, errorConnection);
var res:Responder = new Responder(whenSuccess, whenFail);

connection.connect(gateway);
connection.call('myTwitterOAuth/get_user', res, param);
```

Comment: How do you call the PHP from your ActionScript? In your exemple, it is obvious that `res` is null, but it is impossible to know why unless we see the relevant code.

Answer (score 1):

**Tip:** 
Try first to receive your results from the AMFPHP browser. When you receive your data correctly from the webservice in the browser you'll be able to use it in AS3.0.

Comment: Can you elaborate more if possible? Thanks!

Comment: He's saying test it in the AMFPHP browser first..not really sure of another way of saying that lol

Answer (score 0):

Try this inside the function *whenSuccess* to check what you are really receiving

```
for (var prop in res){
    trace(prop, res[prop]);
}
```

Comment: This is what I'm getting `Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.`